# Queueing batch translations with laravel best method

Tags: laravel, redis, queue

Looking for some guidance on best architecture to accomplish what I am trying to do.  I occasionally get spreadsheets that will have a column of data that will need to be translated.  There could be anywhere from 200 to 10,000 rows in that column.  What I want to do is pull all rows and add them to a redis queue.  I am thinking Redis will be best as I can throttle the queue which is necessary as the api I am calling for translation has throttle limits.  Once the translation is done I will put the translations into a new column and return the user a new spreadsheet with the additional column.

If anyone has ideas for best setup I am open but I want to stick with laravel as that is what the application is already running.  I am just not sure if I should create one queue job and that queue process will just open the file and start doing the translations.  Or do I add a queue for each row of text.  Or lastly do I add all of the rows of text to a table in my database and then have a task scheduler running every minute that will check that table for any untranslated rows and process x amount of them each time is checks.  Not sure about cron job running so frequently when this happens maybe twice a month.

I can see a lot of ways of doing it but looking for an ideal setup as what I don't want to happen is I hit throttle limits and lose potential translations I have done  as it could error out.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Sounds good. What's the question?

Comment: The question is which option should I take to set it up with.  I listed 3 but there may be even better route from a setup and or performance standpoint